# Why sometimes screenshot are completely white using Selenium and geckodriver (firefox)?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, geckodriver

I develop an application using Selenium in JavaScript. The purpose is to automate test using the selenium-driver module.

As example, the application use an input as the JSON below:

```
{
  "output": "out",
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "get",
      "args": {
        "uri":"http://google.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "screenshot",
      "args": {
        "filename": "home"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The `output` field define where all potential outputs should be stored; the `actions` field list all actions which will performed during execution.

Here, the first step is to load *http://google.com*. Next we take a screenshot and save it as *home*.png.

Here's the function called to perform the screenshot. Note that the field `args` of the JSON above actually are the parameter of the function.

```js
execute(client, args) {
    client.driver.takeScreenshot().then(data => {
        const fs = require('fs');
        fs.writeFile(`${client.outputDir}/${args.filename}.png`, data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,''), 'base64', err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is **sometimes** the screenshot work and save the Google's home, and sometime it just  save a white picture.

I don't find someone with the same problem, so I hope someone will help me to fix this problem.

Comment: I wonder if it is an internet speed problem... Like NodeJS load the page, it takes too much time so it's put aside. Then NodeJS continue the execution with the screenshot even if the web page isn't load... Is this possible? I remember that NodeJS has this particularity.

Comment: I add `setTimeout( client.driver.takeScreenshot().then(...), 500 );` and it seems to work. However it isn't a clean solution. If someone know how to force the driver to wait until the page is fully loaded.
N.B: the loadPageStrategy is set to "normal"